# SQL Server 2012 Managment Studio not saving auto recovery files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I tried to go to `Tools > Environment > AutoRecover`.

- The check box of save autorecover is checked.
- Save every "5" minutes.
- Keep autorecover info for: 7 days.

But it doesn't save any auto recover files (I searched inside my user folder for `*.sql`), and doesn't suggest to auto recover when the Management Studio closes by a power down.

I searched the registry to see if something was changed manually in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server` but only found one key: `CustomerFeed`.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/744910/autorecover-information-is-not-saved

Comment: I wonder why microsoft tend to ignore those important bug reports that they always get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [AutoRecover information is not saved](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/744910/autorecover-information-is-not-saved), SSMS 2012 only saves recovery files for queries that have been previously saved (which has led to some complaints). Files that have not been saved seem to get dumped in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp.

So you can check:

- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp

Personally I use TFS for version control on my queries and save them before every run. I've lost a fair number of queries in SSMS so I tend to be very careful.

If you can't find them on disk, there is a way to [recover queries from the procedure cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15035060) as long as you catch them before they get pushed out of the cache. See also [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the info. In my temp folder I just had an empty 0 bytes file .~sql file :(

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this problem in SSMSBoost add-in that I develop:

http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-sql-editor-contents-history

Autorecovery information is saved for all - saved and unsaved docs. You can even navigate through editor contents history and track executed queries.